# Handling long 'important' alerts on mobile

Tags: mobile, notification, alerts

We're challenged on how to handle multiple long alerts for mobile. In some instances they can be so long the rest of the actual content gets pushed down. the content of these alerts are related to various travel restrictions due to covid.

we've tried a few approaches to solutioning this, but either way the user will have to read all of these (since they are important) which isn't a pleasant UX to be honest.

Is there any other way we could approach this solution?

[image]

Comment: Frame challenge: no user could possibly need to read all those alerts at one time. Alerts should only let the user know they some action they are trying to is going to fail. General travel restrictions should not be alerted to a user unless they're trying to take an action that is restricted, and even then only the restriction that applies to that situation should be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a bit other form to signalize user this is important, and show it horizontally in slides so they dont take so much space.

When the user comes to the last slide, instead of prev and next buttons you enable -> "Close".

"Important COVID notices"

/content of the notice/

/prev -- next/

Comment: I've seen something like this before. Maybe another idea is to put a small pager so they know how many notices there are. Like (1/6) for the first notice.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to display a fading paragraph with a content-relevant beginning and a `Read More` button. As this case is an important reading, I would change the tag from `Read more` to `Details`. Clicking this button expand/collapse the whole text. The faded paragraph together with the button makes unnecessary the use of the thick gray divider helping to clean the design.

[image]

Comment: As these are important alerts, doesn't this just increase the chance the user won't read them?

Answer (score 3):

Are all those alerts really relevant for all users? There seem to be quite a few too many for that.

Can you not filter the alerts somehow? That could require you to display some of them at a different stage, for instance after selecting what type of service they want to buy, or selecting an origin or destination, or selecting a specific trip (which dictates transit points, or airlines, etc.)...

Some may be filtered based on the current location of the user as well.

If you really need to display all of them to everyone, do they need to have the full text of the alert for each, or can you just display a title and a button to read more (either by expanding the alert or opening a different page with the details of that alert)?